# What timestamp format does socket.io use?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

Socket.io is sending a timestamp in a url as ?t=1389004155552 during a handshake process.

1389004155 is Mon, 06 Jan 2014 10:29:15 GMT but what are the extra three digits '552' and how would I generate that time format from javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an epoch timestamp but instead of seconds it is represented in milliseconds.

[JavaScript uses milliseconds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to store all time values:

> ...Date objects are based on a time value that is the number of milliseconds since 1 January, 1970 UTC.

For example:

```
var now = new Date();
var epoch_millis = now.getTime();
```

`epoch_millis` will now contain an epoch timestamp in milliseconds.